# React | working with remote data advise ( a conversation )

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I've taken the program at Udacity for react and react native, and it taught me well id say.

Now that I am equipped with the skills and have a good knowledge of the environment and redux etc. Im trying to build my first test app that handles data living remotely.

In the React tutorials we would use local mock data,  and try to fetch it and even simulating the delay with a setTimeout call.  But the problem is the tutorials worked excellent only for the types of apps they were building. I'll get to this in a bit...

My app description:

*At the moment i'm making a test app and so far I can : retrieve a collection of food items ( remote data), render the data,  and press "LIKE" on anyone.  After pressing Like that food item URL gets saved into another remote file under the authedUser's account under a "favorites" property.
The food data at the moment is in a json file hosted on a github repository.
and so is the users account data.*

The thing I noticed in the react course was,  Data would be received into the redux store.
from there anytime you dispatched an action which involved data changes like "Favoriting" something, the app would first dispatch an action to server. Once that resolves it would dispatch to the redux store and affect it there.
Now from what I understand... this is a way to keep the data in sync?   Is this how other applications do it? or is it when data is changed, you only dispatch the change to the server, and request/fetch the new data into redux once the action resolves? The tutorials would receive the initial data, and like this it would be set and stone and then rely on the dispatches to keep it in sync.    would it be better to simply use local state, fetch the data we want. vs using the store?

Im not exactly sure whats best, but to me the idea of receiving the entire data file into the app seems not scalable? like when you use instagram for example,  your phone doesn't download the entire instagram database.    Im thinking it downloads only your profile?  and url's to your friends? etc?

so for this test app that I am trying to make ( described in italic font above ^ )
I'm not sure how to go about it. I definitely don't think its appropriate to receive the entire data file.  I know that I want the user to receive food items onto the screen, but only a handful at a time, maybe through a search it modifies the results on screen. then the user can like a food item.

This is the first time i'm working on an application of this sort, and I do think i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to not integrate Redux at first. Just build the application in plain React.

Now talking about your app. As you said, is a bad idea to download the entire database. When you have to fetch a lot of data a common pattern is to use pagination. It works like this: your app asks for 10 food items. The server returns those 10 and tells you that there is more data and you should make another request if you want to fetch more. It doesn't make sense to fetch 1000 products if the user can see only 10 at a time, right ?

Let's say you like a food item. After you press "like" it is not enough to update your app state, you also need to make the change on the server. How you do this ? Usually you have a food item id(let's say 123) and you maybe you make a POST to https://server.com/like/123. Now that request may fail for various reasons and the server will not register your like. This is way you update the local state only after you successfully updated in the database. In addition you may want to update the number of the likes(maybe other users liked that food item since you fetch) so the server will return the updated number of likes.

Where does Redux fit here ? In React every component has its own state. They can share data between them using props. But this doesn't scale and you will usually end up in a situation called Prop Drilling. Redux store is some kind of global state. For instance:

```
<FoodItems>
  <FoodItem key=1/>
  <FoodItem key=2/>
</FoodItems>
```

Let's say somehow you update the description for the first FoodItem. How do you tell that to other components ? In Redux you dispatch an action and modify the store. Now other components can connect to the store and get the value from there.